# Ubuntu readline() and makefiles

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile

I have really simple program that checks if the word that user types is palindrome: ( I know that this program could be written much better but let's leave that aside for now )


I have to use readline function to get users input or create my own, but because I don't have enough knowledge to create my own I'm using readline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int IsPalindrome(char* niz)
{

int y=0;
int n=0;
int i;
for(i=1;i<strlen(niz)/2+1;i++)
{
    if(niz[i-1]==niz[strlen(niz)-i]){
    y++;
    }
    else{
    n++;
    }

}
    if(n>0){
    return 0;
    }
    else{
    return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *inpt;

    inpt = readline("enter text: ");
    if(IsPalindrome(inpt)==1)
    {
        printf("\nIs palindrome\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNot palindrome\n");
    }  

return 0;
}
```

I'm using Code::Blocks and if I click on "build and run" I get following error:


Undefined reference to 'readline' 


I have to compile and then run my program from terminal with makefile and this is where I'm lost. I just recently started using Ubuntu so I don't really know much about it and how it works.


Now I have to compile my program with makefile ( all in run ). This is makefile that we can use ( I'm at university and we got this as help ) we just have to change some data ( name of the program, add some flags ):

```
GCC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -g
LFLAGS=-lreadline
EXE=main

all: ${EXE}.o
    ${GCC} ${LFLAGS} ${EXE}.o -o ${EXE}

${EXE}.o: ${EXE}.c
    ${GCC} ${CFLAGS} ${EXE}.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf ${EXE}
```

Now because I'm using readline function I added flag **-lreadline** and added name of my program to EXE=**main** ( my program is called main.c ) but if I run makefile ( make all ) I get following error:

```
make all
gcc -lreadline main.o -o main
main.o: In function `main':
/home/yack/Desktop/NPO/Palindrom/Palindrom/main.c:67: undefined reference to `readline'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I installed Readline-6.3 and I was reading on the internet that I have to somehow link readline to tell compiler about it or something but looks like adding **-lreadline** flag is not enough.


Yesterday I found temporary fix so that I could test if my program works with this command:

```
gcc main.c -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lreadline -c -g
```

With this command I managed to create executable file and test if my program works, but today even that doesn't work anymore.


NOTE:

 
I have to compile my program from makefile, the last command in terminal was just to check if my program works since my makefile didn't work.


What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't post images of text! Past the text instead.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry I thought that the error would be better understandable if I posted the picture of what terminal outputs.

Comment: And what keeps you from pasting text as text? Sorry, but that is a lame excuse.

Comment: @Olaf I will keep that in mind for my next questions sorry again, I didn't know that I shouldn't do that.

Comment: Don't just "keep the in mind for the next question", but please edit your **current** one.

Comment: @Olaf Done, I see now why that should be done. Sorry again for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of arguments passed to GCC (and the linker) is relevant.

Your Makefile should have the use of libreadline come before where you actually link libreadline with `LFLAGS`, like so:

```
GCC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -g
LFLAGS=-lreadline
EXE=main

all: ${EXE}.o
    ${GCC} ${EXE}.o -o ${EXE} ${LFLAGS} 

${EXE}.o: ${EXE}.c
    ${GCC} ${CFLAGS} ${EXE}.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf ${EXE}
```

In your "temporary fix" you fixed the ordering, and that is why it worked for you.

Comment: Ty now it created an executable file but when i want to execute it with: ./main i get this error:

Comment: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: UP
Any idea what that might be ?

Comment: It looks like something is botched with your readline installation, but that is not related to your C code or linking.  You probably tried to install readline through some other mechanism than the Ubuntu repositories?  You will want to clean/remove any readline you installed that way, and apt-get install libreadline-dev, if you want the simplest path forward.

Comment: I downloaded .tar.gz -> extracted it -> and installed with command -> ./configure -> and everything else that was posted in installation info. 
I will try to install it again, but I'm happy that my makefile works now ty very much.

Comment: We are drifting way out of scope here, but try `apt-get install libreadline-dev`. After removing `/usr/local/include/readline`(dir with contents), `/usr/local/lib/libreadline*` and `/usr/local/lib/libhistory*`

Comment: @Jon Kåre Hellan I managet to fix the problem with this:
1. cd /usr/local/lib
2. sudo mkdir temp
3. sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libreadline* temp
4. sudo ldconfig
5. sudo apt-get update

So it's fixed now but ty for trying to help me